# nth-child(odd) selecting everything

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply style for alternate rows, here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9em2dxzr/)
Why is it selecting all?

```
li { background: green; }
         li:nth-child(odd) { background: red; }
```

Comment: because it does not have `<ul>` parent

Comment: @Sushant Bajracharya see the answer. ?

Comment: First of all I give Your answer @Sushant Bajracharya look time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<Br>` is also counted in this case. So all of your li become odd number.
Such as ..

1. li
2. br
3. li
4. br

That is why your normal li selector didn't apply since `li:nth-child(odd) { background: red; }` overwrite all li.
remove br tag and it should be fine.

Comment: glad to know it help :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove `<br>` in your html code. It's work.

Answer (score 2):

I think a more elegant solution is to use `nth-of-type` instead, then you don't need to remove the `<br/>`s

```
li { background: green; }
li:nth-of-type(odd) { background: red; }
```

If you want to learn more about the different nth-of-whatever options, [this css-tricks interactive tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/) may interest you